# Excel IF() Formula To Check for Numeric Characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016

What I am after here is if the value in cell C4 is numeric and >= 1 then I want to multiply that value by 300 and add it to C10*.26) if C4 is non numeric or is 0 then I only want to show C10*.26 in the cell

This is the formula I have

```
=if(C4<>"", (300*C4)+(C10*.26),(C10*.62))
```

Which this works, but if a non-numeric value is input then the formula errors with `#VALUE!`

Is the best way to combat this to encompass the formula in an `IFERROR()` function, or does Excel 2016 have a built in way of checking if a cell value is numeric?"

Comment: if its zero are you supposed to multiply by .26 as you say in your question or multiply by .62 as you show in your formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with ISNUMBER.

```
=if(AND(ISNUMBER(C4), IFERROR(VALUE(C4), FALSE)), (300*C4)+(C10*.26), (C10*.62))
```

Comment: Adding in the AND() statement returns the #Value! error

Comment: @Jeeped out of curiousity, why do you even need the isnumber check? wouldn't `=IF(IFERROR(VALUE(C4),0),(C300*C4)+(C10*0.26),(C10*0.62))` give the same results? "0 is false everything else is true" - JEEPED

Comment: @ForwardEd - You don't. Zero x anything is zero but I misread the formula as a x not a + and had already edited a few times before I realized my error.

Answer (score 1):

you can try :

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C4),C4>=1), (300*C4)+(C10*0.26),(C10*0.62))
```

Hope this helps